# How do I add a combobox to a message in pygtk?

Tags: python, combobox, dialog, gtk, pygtk

How do I add a combo box to a pop-up window and return the result that the user selects?  I am trying to adapt code from other examples I've seen, as the gtk documentation isn't terribly clear.  I am things along the lines of the following, but am getting nowhere fast (or, very slowly, to be more accurate).

```
        message = gtk.Dialog(title=None,
                             parent=None,
                             flags=0,
                             buttons=None)

        combo = gtk.combo_box_new_text()
        for key in self.MyBom.potential_keywords:
            combo.append_text(key)
        combo.set_active(0)

        cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        combo.pack_start(cell, True)
        combo.add_attribute(cell, 'text', 0)

        response = 0

        message.add_action_widget(combo, response)
        response = message.run()
```

Comment: You should explain the actual problem you have, we're not all psychic. As a comment: don't mix ComboBoxText api (`combo_box_new_text()` and `append_text`) with actual ComboBox packing api (the cell renderer using part): you need to use one or the other. Also, after running the messagedialog you probably want to check the active item in the combo, right?

Answer (score 0):

`add_action_widget()` needs an activatable widget.
You might try using `get_content_area()` (a VBox) and packing the combo box into it.  You could then connect the "changed" signal to destroy the dialog.